# An exercise in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following question:

Let $f: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a function such that it's real and imaginary part is differentiable at $z = 0$ in the sense of $\mathbb R^2$, assume further 
$$
      L =   \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \biggr| \frac{  f(z)  }{  z  } \biggr|
$$
exists. Prove that either $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z)}$ is holomorphic at $z = 0$.

I am asking is there a better solution rather then the following brutal force one I will present.

Since $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ exists, we know $f(z) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$ is a continuous function. So
$$
 |f(0) | = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0 } | f(z) | = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} |z | \biggr| \frac{ f(z ) }{ z } \biggr| = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} | z | \cdot \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \biggr| \frac{ f(z) }{ z } \biggr| = 0 \cdot L = 0
$$
So, $f(0) = 0 \Longrightarrow u(0, 0) = v(0 , 0) = 0$. We split the case for $L = 0$ and $L \ne 0$. If $L = 0$, we have
$$
 \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \biggr| \frac{ f(z + 0) - f(0) }{z} - 0  \biggr|  = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \biggr| \frac{ f(z) }{ z } \biggr| = 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{ f(z + 0) - f(0) }{z } = 0 
$$
In this case $f$ is holomorphic at $z = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$.

Now, assume $L \ne 0$, from the assumption, we know $u, v: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are differentiable function at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ in the $\mathbb R^2$ sense. So $f(z) = f(x, y) = (u(x, y), v(x, y))$ when viewed as function from $\mathbb R^2$ to itself is also differentiable at the origin. From definition, there exists a linear map $A: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ such that for $h \in \mathbb R^2$ sufficiently close to $(0, 0)$ we have
$$
 f(h) = f(0) + A \cdot h + \epsilon(h) \text{ where } \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ | \epsilon( h) | }{ | h| } = 0 \tag{$\ast$}
$$
It follows from $(\ast)$ that 
$$
 \frac{ | f(h) | }{ | h| } = \frac{ | A \cdot h + \epsilon (h) | }{ | h| }
$$
By triangle inequality, 
$$
 \biggr| \frac{ | A \cdot h | }{ | h | } - \frac{ | \epsilon (h) | }{ | h| } \biggr| \leq \frac{ | f(h) | }{ | h | } \leq \frac{ | A \cdot h | }{ | h | } + \frac{ | \epsilon(h) | }{ | h| }
$$
Take limit as $h$ approach to the origin on both sides of above inequality, we have
$$
 \biggr| \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 }  \frac{ | A \cdot h | }{ | h | } - \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ | \epsilon (h) | }{ | h| } \biggr| \leq L \leq \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ | A \cdot h | }{ | h | } + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ | \epsilon (h) | }{ | h | }
$$
because $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0 } | f(z) | / | z | = L$ from assumption. Next, we put $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } | \epsilon (h) | / | h | = 0$ obtained in $(\ast)$ to above inequality 
$$
 \biggr| \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 }  \frac{ | A \cdot h | }{ | h | } - 0 \biggr| \leq L \leq \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ | A \cdot h | }{ | h | } + 0 \Longrightarrow \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ | Ah | }{ | h | } = L \in \mathbb R_+
$$
So $| A h | / | h | \rightarrow L \in \mathbb R_+$ for any vector which approaches to the origin from any direction. Let 
$$
 A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
 \end{pmatrix}
 \text{ where } a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R
$$
Take $h = (-tb, ta) \in \mathbb R^2$. By calculation, $A h = (0, (ad -bc)t )$, it follows that $| h| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} |t |, | Ah | = | ad - bc | \cdot |t |$, 
$$
 \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ | Ah | }{ | h | } = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{ | (ad - bc) t | }{ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} |t | } =  \frac{ | ad - bc | }{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} }
$$
Since $L \ne 0$, we have $L = | ad - bc | / \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}  = \det A / \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \ne 0 \Rightarrow | \det A | \ne 0 \Longrightarrow A$ is invertible. Now, take $h = (t, 0)$ then $Ah = (at, ct), | h | = | t |, | Ah | = \sqrt{a^2 + c^2} | t |$, it follows that
$$
 L = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{ |A h | }{ | h | } = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \sqrt{a^2 + c^2 } | t | }{ | t | } = \sqrt{a^2 + c^2}
$$
Similarly, direct calculation can show
$$
 L = 
 \begin{cases}
  \sqrt{b^2 + d^2 }       &\text{ when we take $h = (0, t)$} \\
  \sqrt{ (a + b)^2 + (c + d)^2 } / \sqrt{2}    &\text{ when we take $h = (t, t)$} \\
  \sqrt{ (a - b)^2 + (c - d)^2 }  / \sqrt{2}    &\text{ when we take $h = (t, -t)$}   
 \end{cases}
$$
Observe 
$$
 \frac{ \sqrt{(a + b)^2 + (c + d)^2 } }{ \sqrt{2} } = \frac{ \sqrt{ (a - b)^2 + (c - d )^2 }}{ \sqrt{2} } \Longrightarrow ab + cd = 0 \tag{7.1}
$$
Since $L^2 = a^2 + c^2 = b^2 + d^2$, we deduce $a^2 - b^2 = d^2 - c^2$, square both sides we have
$$
 (a^2 - b^2)^2 = (d^2 - c^2)^2 \iff a^4 + b^4 - 2a^2b^2 = c^4 + d^4 - 2c^2d^2
$$
It follows from above that $a^4 + b^4 = c^4 + d^4$ for $ab + cd = 0 \rightarrow ab = -cd \rightarrow a^2b^2 = c^2d^2$. So
$$
 a^4 + b^4 = c^4 + d^4 \Longrightarrow a^4 - c^4 = d^4 - b^4 \Longrightarrow (a^2 + c^2)(a^2 - c^2) = (d^2 + b^2)(d^2 - b^2)
$$
Because $L^2 = a^2 + c^2 = b^2 + d^2 > 0$, $(a^2 + c^2)(a^2 - c^2) = (d^2 + b^2)(d^2 - b^2) \rightarrow L^2(a^2 - c^2) = L^2(d^2 - b^2) \rightarrow a^2 - c^2 = d^2 - b^2$. Together with $a^2 + c^2 = b^2 + d^2$, we get
$$
 a^2 = \frac{a^2 + c^2 }{2} + \frac{a^2 - c^2}{2} = \frac{b^2 + d^2}{2} + \frac{d^2 - b^2}{2} = d^2, c^2 = b^2 + d^2 - a^2 = b^2
$$
So, $d = \pm a, b = \pm c$. Hence we have to consider the following four cases
$$
 (1) \, d = a, b = c; (2)\, d = -a, b = c; (3)\, d = a, b = -c; (4) \, d= -a, b = -c \tag{7.2}
$$
Recall if $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z)}$ is holomorphic at $z = 0$, then the Jacobian matrix of $f(z) $ and $\overline{ f(z) }$ 
$$
 J(f(z) ) = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  u_x & u_y \\
  v_x & v_y 
 \end{pmatrix} \;
 J (\overline{f(z) } ) = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  u_x & -u_y \\
  v_x & -v_y 
 \end{pmatrix}
 \text{ is of the form}
 \begin{pmatrix}
   p & -q \\
  q & p
 \end{pmatrix}
 \tag{$\ast \ast$}
$$
We want to show in any of the cases from $(7.2)$, the linear map $A$ when treated as the Jacobian for $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z) }$ satisfies condition $(\ast \ast)$. That is either $a = d, c = -b$ or $a = -d, c = b$.

For the first case, since $ab + cd = 2ac = 0 \Rightarrow a =0$ or $c = 0$. Since $\det A = a^2 - c^2 \ne 0$, if $a = 0$ then $c \ne 0 \Rightarrow a = 0 = -d, b = c$. If $c = 0$ then $a \ne 0 \Rightarrow a = d, c = 0 = -b$ both satisfies $(\ast \ast)$. For the second case, $d = -a \iff a = -d$ together with $c = b$ they automatically satisfies condition $(\ast)$. For the third case, same result follows because $b = -c \iff c = -b$. Last but not least, for $d = -a, b = -c$, we deduce $ab + cd = a(-c) + c(-a) = -2ac = 0 \Rightarrow ac = 0 \Rightarrow a = 0$ or $c = 0$. Since $\det A = ad - bc = a(-a) - (-c)c = c^2 - a^2 \ne 0$, in this case we have either $a = 0, c \ne 0$ or $a \ne 0, c =0$. If $a = 0, c \ne 0$, $a = 0 = d, b = -c$. If $c = 0, a \ne 0$, $a = -d, c = 0 = b$ both also satisfy condition $(\ast \ast)$. Hence, we have checked all possible cases for $A$ which implies either $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z) }$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann conditions at $z = 0$. Therefore either $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z) }$ is holomorphic at $z = 0$.

Comment: Note: For $f(z) = \lvert z\rvert^2$, neither of $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z)}$ (which, by the way is the same in this case) is holomorphic at $z = 0$. $f$ is complex differentiable at $z=0$, that's less than holomorphic (holomorphic at $z_0$ = complex differentiable in a neighbourhood of $z_0$). Concerning the question, using the Wirtinger derivatives gives a much shorter computation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! You are right, I should say $f$ is complex differentiable at $z = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

The task becomes much easier when we use the Wirtinger derivatives. We must have $f(0) = 0$ for $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \left\lvert\frac{f(z)}{z}\right\rvert$ to exist (finitely), so the real-differentiability of $u$ and $v$, hence $f$, means that we have an identity

$$f(z) = a\cdot z + b \cdot \overline{z} + \lvert z\rvert\cdot h(z)$$

with $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} h(z) = 0$; $a = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0)$, and $b = \frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline{z}}(0)$. $f(z)$ is complex differentiable in $0$ if and only if $b = 0$, and $\overline{f(z)}$ is complex differentiable in $0$ if and only if $a = 0$. Writing $z = r e^{i\varphi}$, we have

$$\frac{f(re^{i\varphi})}{re^{i\varphi}} = a + b e^{-2i\varphi} + e^{-i\varphi}\cdot h(re^{i\varphi}).$$

Keeping $\varphi$ fixed and letting $r \searrow 0$, we have

$$\lim_{r\searrow 0} \frac{f(re^{i\varphi})}{re^{i\varphi}} = a + b e^{-2i\varphi}.$$

The set of all these limit points is a circle with radius $\lvert b\rvert$ and centre $a$. If $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \left\lvert \frac{f(z)}{z}\right\rvert$ exists, all the limit points $a + b e^{-2i\varphi}$ must have the same modulus, and that means that the radius $\lvert b\rvert$ or the centre $a$ of the circle must be $0$, i.e. $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z)}$ must be complex differentiable in $0$. (And this also shows the converse, if $f(z)$ or $\overline{f(z)}$ is complex differentiable in $0$, then $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} \left\lvert \frac{f(z)}{z}\right\rvert$ exists.)